# Generating a boundary mesh from a list of points

Tags: differential-equations, mesh, finite-element-method

I have a list of points from which I am trying to generate a mesh:

```
 {{{261.324, 937.805}, {1139.98, 937.843}}, {{261.324, 
   937.805}, {261.014, 57.1923}}, {{1140.95, 505.675}, {705.906, 
   57.3194}}, {{1578.03, 507.712}, {1139.98, 937.843}}, {{261.014, 
   57.1923}, {705.906, 57.3194}}, {{1140.95, 505.675}, {1578.03, 
   507.712}}}
```

`fldd` is a list of coordinates (without duplicates) generated by flattening the given array and using the `DeleteDuplicates` command. That definitely works. However, the `BoundaryElements` part of the command is giving me issues.

I use the following code to generate the connectivity array which tells *Mathematica* in what order to connect the points:

```
cn = {}
For[c1 = 1, c1 <= len, c1++,
 For[c2 = 1, c2 <= 2, c2++,
  holder = Position[lines, lines[[c1, c2]]];
  sholder = Sort[holder];
  Print[sholder];
  If[FreeQ[cn, {sholder[[1, 1]], sholder[[2, 1]]}],
   Print["In If"];
   AppendTo[cn, {sholder[[1, 1]], sholder[[2, 1]]}]
   ]
  ]
 ]
```

When I run the code below to actually generate the boundary mesh, I get an error:

```
bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh["Coordinates" -> fldd[[1 ;; Length[fldd]]], 
  "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[cn[[1 ;; Length[cn]]]]}]
```

> ToBoundaryMesh::fememib: The input has or generated an intersecting boundary and cannot be processed. >>

I can't really see what's going wrong. I know that the loop above generates a list of numbers of the form:

```
{{startpoint1, endpoint1}, ..., {startpointN, endpointN}}
```

This looks identical to the examples I've seen. I also know that the points I want connected are connected, and each point is listed as a vertex for 2 lines, which is what I want geometrically. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Full code is:

```
lines = {
   {{261.324, 937.805}, {1139.98, 937.843}},
   {{261.324, 937.805}, {261.014, 57.1923}}, 
   {{1140.95, 505.675}, {705.906, 57.3194}}, 
   {{1578.03, 507.712}, {1139.98, 937.843}}, 
   {{261.014, 57.1923}, {705.906, 57.3194}},
   {{1140.95, 505.675}, {1578.03, 507.712}}
  };


len = Length[lines];
fl = Flatten[lines, 1];
fldd = DeleteDuplicates[fl];

(*To find connectivity (Uggh)*)
cn = {};
For[c1 = 1, c1 <= len, c1++,
 For[c2 = 1, c2 <= 2, c2++,
  holder = Position[lines, lines[[c1, c2]]];
  sholder = Sort[holder];
  Print[sholder];
  If[FreeQ[cn, {sholder[[1, 1]], sholder[[2, 1]]}],
   Print["In If"];
   AppendTo[cn, {sholder[[1, 1]], sholder[[2, 1]]}]
  ]
 ]
]

bmesh = ToBoundaryMesh[
    "Coordinates" -> fldd[[1 ;; Length[fldd]]], 
    "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement[cn[[1 ;; Length[cn]]]]}
  ]
bmesh["Wireframe"]
emesh = ToElementMesh[bmesh]
emesh["Wireframe"]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is the fact that the lines in your list of lines are not contiguous, or in other words the points in your `fldd` list generated from the `lines` variable are not each other's nearest neighbors.

Another issue may be the nested `For` loops. If you find yourself using procedural constructs such as looping constructs, you might want to rethink your approach, since there will typically be a more efficient and often simpler one using a functional approach instead. In other words, you want to get into the mindset of telling *Mathematica* *what* you want done, and not *how* to do it! It is brain-twisting at first, but it pays off in the long run.

**The problem:** First of all, let's see why `ToBoundaryMesh` was complaining in your original implementation. I will use the definition of `lines` that you provided in the following. This is along the lines of what you were trying to do:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]

points = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[lines, 1]];

ToBoundaryMesh[
  "Coordinates" -> points,
  "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement@Partition[Range[Length[points]], 2, 1]}
]["Wireframe"]
```

[image: wrong mesh]

As you can see, the mesh is generated from the points *in the order in which you provide them*. When you attempted to close that mesh region by connecting the top leftmost point with the rightmost point, the function found that this last `LineElement` would intersect one of the existing lines, and threw an error.

**The solution:** We need to order your points in such a way that they can be traversed in a continuous path that goes through each of them once. Sounds familiar? It may, because this is more or less the classical traveling salesman problem. Fortunately, *Mathematica* already has a built in function to accomplish that: `FindShortestTour`. This function takes a list of points, and returns the length of the tour (we don't care about that), and a list of indices that indicates in what order one should take the original points to generate this closed path: this last piece of information is exactly what we need.

```
boundarymesh =
  ToBoundaryMesh[
   "Coordinates" -> points,
   "BoundaryElements" -> {LineElement@ Partition[Last@FindShortestTour[points], 2, 1]}
   ];

boundarymesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: correct boundary mesh]

Now that we have the boundary mesh, we can create an element mesh from it:

```
elementmesh = ToElementMesh[boundarymesh];

elementmesh["Wireframe"]
```

[image: element mesh]

**The functional approach:** Note how much easier it is to produce your desired connectivity array using a more idiomatic approach than `For` loops. Let's dissect what is going on in the generation of the `BoundaryElements` list:

```
ordering = Last@FindShortestTour[points]
Partition[ordering, 2, 1]
```

In this case, `Partition` picks elements out of the `ordering` list two at a time (second argument), with an overlap between the generated lists of one element (the third argument). The output of the above is:

```
output of FindShortestTour: {1, 3, 5, 4, 6, 2, 1}
output of Partition:        {{1, 3}, {3, 5}, {5, 4}, {4, 6}, {6, 2}, {2,1}}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the detailed response. I just started MMA, so you going into your coding logic was helpful. Is there a possibility that a more convoluted shape would lead to incorrect connectivity? For instance, if two points were very close together could they be connected if it's the shortest path?

Comment: @PCK I think the best way to find out would be to try it out!